# Difference between strong and uniform operator topologies

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, operator-theory, banach-spaces

I am currently a little confused regarding the difference between the strong and uniform operator topologies. I know that, if $T , T_n : V \rightarrow W$, then $T_n \rightarrow T$ in the uniform operator topology if:

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \vert \vert T - T_n \vert \vert = 0 $$

For some sequence of bounded operators $T_n$. Additionally, I know that $T_n \rightarrow T$ in the strong operator topology if:

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \vert \vert (T - T_n)x \vert \vert_W = 0 $$

For any $x \in V$ (or is it for all $x \in V$? maybe this is where my confusion stems from). My confusion is in regard to the operator norm, since the operator norm is defined as:

$$ \vert \vert T \vert \vert_{op} = \sup _{x \in V} \vert \vert T \frac{x}{\vert \vert x \vert \vert_V} \vert \vert_W $$

Using this in the definition for the uniform operator topology, we get:

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{x \in V} \vert \vert (T - T_n) \frac{x}{\vert \vert x \vert \vert_V} \vert \vert_W = 0 $$

Which is pretty similar to the strong operator topology, and so I'm confused as to how they differ. It is obvious to me that there is an additional factor of $\frac{1}{\vert \vert x \vert \vert_V}$ in the uniform operator definition, but I am struggling to see how they would really differ. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are missing a "sup" in your last formula.

Comment: Ah okay thanks for that. Any idea how to help me distinguish the two? Thanks.

Comment: You might want to read my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4437276/what-will-be-the-next-step-to-ensure-that-the-pointwise-convergence-implies-conv, specially point (4).